# Get-WinEvent with match TimeCreated

Tags: powershell, date, match, where-clause, get-winevent

I'm looking to idea how to check whole Windows log for event matched particular date ex:
At the moment stopped on "System" log :(

`Get-WinEvent System | where {$_.TimeCreated -eq "24.03.2021 20:50:37"}`

but results show me nothing.
I want to use script to search all events not only System.
I need to correlate date with events.
My script looks like this:

`(Get-WinEvent –ListLog * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LogName | ForEach-Object {Get-WinEvent | where $_.TimeCreated -eq "24.03.2021 20:50:37"}}`

but got syntax error

Comment: Compare `TimeCreated` against another `DateTime` object, not a string. Plus you are narrowing it down to Hour, Minute and Second.. Do you really need it that strict?

Comment: Yes I need very accurate data.

Comment: Did theo's suggestion work?

Comment: yes theo works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the measure of accuracy you are after. (a date complete with Hours, Minutes and Seconds, but **without** the Milliseconds)

When you create a comparison DateTime object with

```
$time = [datetime]'03/24/2021 20:50:37'
```

you will find its `.MilliSecond` property is set to 0.

As you are comparing this to the events `TimeCreated` property, chances are ***very*** slim that date actually has that exact time with a MiliSecond also valued `0`..

This is why you need to strip off the milliseconds (and also the fractions of those milliseconds) from the `TimeCreated` property of the events in order to be able to compare with an exact date, but without milliseconds:

```
$time = [datetime]'03/24/2021 20:50:37'
(Get-WinEvent -LogName System) | 
    Where-Object { ($_.TimeCreated.AddTicks(-$_.TimeCreated.Ticks % [timespan]::TicksPerSecond)) -eq $time }
```

You can of course put this in a loop to scan different log names if you want

---

As per your comment, The `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet returns objects with a lot of properties. The standard way of PowerShell is to output on screen a **subset** of these properties, in this case `TimeCreated, Id, LevelDisplayName and Message`.

If you also want the name of the event log in this output, add a Select-Object to the command like:

```
$time = [datetime]'04/19/2021 08:38:20' 
(Get-WinEvent –ListLog * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LogName | ForEach-Object {
    Get-WinEvent -LogName $_ | 
        Where-Object { ($_.TimeCreated.AddTicks(-$_.TimeCreated.Ticks % [timespan]::TicksPerSecond)) -eq $time} |
        # output the properties you are interested in
        Select-Object LogName, TimeCreated, Id, LevelDisplayName, Message
}
```

To make it more flexible, **capture** the result in a variable so you can both display on screen, and also save the results to a Csv file for later inspection:

```
$time   = [datetime]'04/19/2021 08:38:20' 
$result = (Get-WinEvent –ListLog * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LogName | ForEach-Object {
    Get-WinEvent -LogName $_ | 
        Where-Object { ($_.TimeCreated.AddTicks(-$_.TimeCreated.Ticks % [timespan]::TicksPerSecond)) -eq $time} |
        # output the properties you are interested in
        Select-Object LogName, TimeCreated, Id, LevelDisplayName, Message
}

# output on screen
$result

# save to Csv File
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'Path\To\The\Output.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

<sup>To see what all the properties returned are named, you can do

`Get-WinEvent -LogName System | Select-Object -First 1 | fl *`</sup>

Comment: Your idea works !!! Trying merge your resolution with all logs withc ForEach but without luck :/    (Get-WinEvent –ListLog * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LogName | ForEach-Object Get-WinEvent | Where-Object { ($_.TimeCreated.AddTicks(-$_.TimeCreated.Ticks % [timespan]::TicksPerSecond)) -eq $time }  shows many errors.

Comment: @CurUser What you post in the comment seems incomplete. Try `ForEach-Object { Get-WinEvent -LogName $_ | Where-Object {...} }`

Comment: This cmd works great: `$time = [datetime]'04/19/2021 08:38:20'
(Get-WinEvent –ListLog * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LogName | 
ForEach-Object {Get-WinEvent -LogName $_ | Where-Object { ($_.TimeCreated.AddTicks(-$_.TimeCreated.Ticks % [timespan]::TicksPerSecond)) -eq $time} } `   but cant get it work with `Write-Host $_`  to get *name event log* where detailed log was found

Comment: @CurlUser Please see my edit. It explains how to return more useful properties

Answer (score 0):

TimeCreated is a DateTime type property, so a compatible string works better.  (Not the same thing as starttime for a filterhashtable?)

```
Get-WinEvent system | select timecreated | select -first 1 | % timecreated | 
  % gettype

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType


[datetime]'03/24/2021 20:50:37'

Wednesday, March 24, 2021 8:50:37 PM

# timecreated must have 0 milliseconds
get-winevent system | where timecreated -eq '03/24/2021 20:50:37'
```

One idea for the millisecond problem:

```
get-winevent system | where { $_.timecreated.tostring() -eq '3/24/2021 8:50:37 PM' }
```

I'm surprised something like this doesn't work.

```
get-winevent system | where '3/24/2021 8:50:37 PM' -eq timecreated


'3/24/2021 8:50:37 PM' -eq [datetime]'3/24/2021 8:50:37 PM'

False
```

Ugh got it.  Tostring() doesn't format time this way.

```
[string][datetime]'3/24/2021 8:50:37 PM'

03/24/2021 20:50:37


'03/24/2021 20:50:37' -eq [datetime]'3/24/2021 8:50:37 PM'

True
```

So the left arg to -eq determines a string comparison:

```
get-winevent system | where '03/24/2021 20:50:37' -eq timecreated
```